# find closest point from users coordinates

Tags: java, hashmap, coordinates, user-input

I would like to know how to use find the closes point using coordinates. i am using a Hashmap which holds coordinates and strings. i have allowed the user to input an x and y axis and store them as int a and int b but i don't know where to go from there. thanks for looking

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Coordinate {

static class Coords {
    int x;
    int y;

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        Coords c = (Coords) o;
        return c.x == x && c.y == y;
    }

    public Coords(int x, int y) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return new Integer(x + "0" + y);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return x + ";" + y;
    }


}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    HashMap<Coords, String> map = new HashMap<Coords, String>();

    map.put(new Coords(250, 140), "Clifton street");
    map.put(new Coords(195, 115), "twoli");
    map.put(new Coords(165, 95), "Jacobs well");
    map.put(new Coords(140, 90), "moxbridge");
    map.put(new Coords(55, 95), "parkway");
    map.put(new Coords(15, 120), "easton");
    map.put(new Coords(260, 25), "Weston on shore");
    map.put(new Coords(250, 60), "newbridge");
    map.put(new Coords(185, 85), "central");
    map.put(new Coords(140, 100), "stdennis");
    map.put(new Coords(85, 140), "trim bridge");
    map.put(new Coords(170, 35), "windmill hill");
    map.put(new Coords(150, 60), "shakespeare court");
    map.put(new Coords(95, 50), "temple fields");
    map.put(new Coords(55, 125), "pirac cresent");
    map.put(new Coords(150, 155), "st judes hill");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i;
    int a;
    int b;

    System.out.println(map.size());
    System.out.println(map.toString());
    Coords c = new Coords(65,72);
    System.out.println(c + " - " + map.get(c));

    System.out.println("choose from the following");
    System.out.println("find closest station = 1");
    System.out.println("plan train route = 2");
    i = input.nextInt();

    if (i==1){
        System.out.println("enter your x axis ");
        a = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter your y axis");
        b = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("the nearest station is");
    }
    else if (i==2){
        System.out.println("route planner");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("entered incorrect number");

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why dont you use the Point class that comes with Java?

Comment: @KevinMangold @Djchunky123 `awt.Point` represents a pixel on your screen, not generic coordinates. And it doesn't have this misnamed/buggy `hashCode` method - try input `x=101` and `y=1` vs. `x=1` and `y=101` :D

Comment: @amon True, but it does contain distance and distanceSq methods that can be used to help.

Comment: @amon, it is impossible for a `hashCode` is unique. How do you judge it to be "misnamed/buggy"?

Comment: @veer It is just very simple to create a collision, even trivial to a degree that an application depending on a higher uniqueness might break, e.g. using these "hashes" as keys of a map.

Comment: @amon, the Oracle implementation of `HashMap` utilizes separate chaining to handle collisions. I don't quite understand what would break here. That being said, I agree that the `hashCode` does indeed look naive, but, again, I don't think it should break anything.

Comment: @amon PPS Oracle's [`HashMap`](http://goo.gl/JRSvM) uses an additional [*mixing* step](http://bretm.home.comcast.net/~bretm/hash/3.html) in order to protect against poorer hashes.

Comment: @veer Thank you for these wonderful links. I herewith renounce what I said about the `hashCode` buggyness and will henceforth only call it *suboptimal*. Neither OP's code nor the Java `HashMap` implementation is naive, but only my dwarfed imagination about how a *HashMap* could be implemented.

Comment: @amon No problem dude, just wanted to share knowledge :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, I advise you take KevinMangold's advice, seeing as Java provides a perfectly suitable [Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) class for you to use.

---

This is a *minimization* problem. Essentially, you want to compute the distance between the entered point and every known station using some metric (perhaps [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)?). Then, you pick the station corresponding to the minimum distance found.

Here's some example code using [Collections.min](http://goo.gl/EUUQX):

```
final Map<Point, String> names = ...;
final Set<Point> stations = names.keySet();
final Point source = ...;
final Point nearest = Collections.min(stations, new Comparator<Point>() {

  public int compare(final Point p1, final Point p2) {
    return (int) p1.distanceSq(p2);
  }
});
final String name = names.get(nearest);
```

Comment: Using this method the same distances will be recalculated many times. If you need to maximize the speed, you may want to adopt [an alternative solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23042847/1600770).

Comment: @Agostino the distances could just be cached with a few more lines of code