# Closest point of a set to a given point

Tags: java, sorting

I have a ArrayList of 2 dimensional points represented by [this](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/12oop/Point2D.java.html) class. I get the x and y coordinates from a mouse click of the user and I have to find the closest point at this set to the point obtained by the user's mouse. I've find the following topic while I was trying to solve this

[find closest point from users coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819082/find-closest-point-from-users-coordinates)

The Point2D class have a comparator called DISTANCE_TO_ORDER that compares two points using the distance to a third one. I've tried the following to obtain the closest point:

```
public Point2D closestPoint(Point2D p){
    return Collections.min(points, p.DISTANCE_TO_ORDER);
}
```

but I get the error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
when I try

```
Point2D p = new Point2D(-46.73081652, -23.557997478347108);
Point2D c = gps.closestPoint(p);
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried to implement something like the topic, but didn't work. Can someone help me to solve this?

PS: I have to use the Point2D class.

Thanks!

Comment: What are `points` in the first snippet and `gps` in the second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the JavaDoc on `Collections.min(collection, comparator)`:

> throws NoSuchElementException if the collection is empty.

Hence most probably `points` is empty.

Comment: Indeed, it was empty. I forgot to call the method that fills it. Thanks for your answer.